# Windows Virtual Address Space

Tags: windows, pointers, system, cheat-engine

as I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/virtual-address-space) the virtual address space of a 32 bit Windows application has 2GB of storage (from 0x00000000-0x7FFFFFFF). The other 2GB are reserved for the system address space.

However, I found a pointer in a 32bit program (using Cheat Engine) which is pointing to an address which isn't in range of the virutal address space. The addresses in my last exploration were 0x301DDC3C -> 0x87F56190 like you can see in the picture:
[image]

(The expansion in the first line means a dereference of the pointer 0x301DDC3C, in the next line you can see what's in the dereference location 0x87F56190 in RAM)

After dereferencing the pointer there are pointers back into the process virtual address space.

**How is it possible that a user mode application has a valid pointer into system address space?**

Does this mean the pointer in location 0x301DDC3C is pointing to an location in the system address space? And so the process I'm examining is using kernel mode stuff?

Comment: if 32bit executable marked with [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=vs-2017) run under 64bit windows - full 4gb space is avaible for application

Comment: check for `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics`

Comment: @RbMm Nice hint. Thank you. It's defined. So it must be a normal address in the private address space of the application...

Comment: yes, if you run 32-bit app with `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` - the up to `FFFE0000` is avaible for 32 bit code. really user space up to `7FFFFFFF0000`

Comment: Setting the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag for my application fixed my problem. When you write an answer with some more explaination, in which cases a pointer > 0x7FFFFFFF can appear, I could mark it as correct answer. (Helped me a lot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Memory and Address Space Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#memory_limits)

Limits on memory and address space vary by platform, operating system, and by whether the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag in the [`IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_file_header). `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` (*The application can handle addresses larger than 2 GB*) is set or cleared by using the [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=vs-2017) linker option.

by default `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` cleared  for 32-bit PE and set for 64-bit PE, but we can overwrite default:

[image]

so 32-bit process with set `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag - up to 4Gb memory is avaible.

really of course `[0, 0x800000000000)` (win8.1 +) or `[0, 0x80000000000)` (before win 8.1) memory space is avaible for user mode in x64 windows.  but system artificially restrict this by reserve big range of memory (this allocation is protected and can not be free)

for 32-bit process this reservation begin from `7FFF0000` or `FFFE0000` and up to 64-bit *ntdll.dll*. very interesting that in 64-bit process, where `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` cleared - also was such reserved memory space begin from `0x80000000`. also interesting that in this case *kernel32.dll* is loaded at another address compare usual 64-bit process. so base of *kernel32.dll* not the same in general in all 64-bit processes. but *ntdll.dll* loaded at the same address in all processes anyway.

usual memory allocations on x64 windows:

1. 32 bit process, `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` cleared (default)
   [image]
2. 32 bit process, `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` set
   [image]
3. 64 bit process, `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` cleared
   [image]
4. 64 bit process, `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` set (default)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

*ALL* of the addresses you see are *virtual* addresses, of the *process* (not "physical" addresses).  A user-space process may use pointers that happen to come from "system space", but that does *NOT* mean a process can freely access kernel resources , nor does it mean that these pointers necessarily map to *physical* addresses.

Here is another Microsoft link, that might help clarify:

> [Virtual Address Space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces)
>
> When a processor reads or writes to a memory location, it uses a
>   virtual address. As part of the read or write operation, the processor
>   translates the virtual address to a physical address.
>
> ...
>
> The range of
>   virtual addresses that is available to a process is called the virtual
>   address space for the process. Each user-mode process has its own
>   private virtual address space. For a 32-bit process, the virtual
>   address space is usually the 2-gigabyte range 0x00000000 through
>   0x7FFFFFFF.
>
> ...
>
> Processes like Notepad.exe and MyApp.exe run in user
>   mode. Core operating system components and many drivers run in the
>   more privileged kernel mode. For more information about processor
>   modes, see User mode and kernel mode. Each user-mode process has its
>   own private virtual address space, but all code that runs in kernel
>   mode shares a single virtual address space called system space. The
>   virtual address space for a user-mode process is called user space.
>
> ...
>
> In 32-bit Windows, the total available virtual address space is
>   2^32 bytes (4 gigabytes). Usually the lower 2 gigabytes are used for
>   user space, and the upper 2 gigabytes are used for system space.
>
> ...
>
> Code running in user mode has access to user space but does not have
>   access to system space. This restriction prevents user-mode code from
>   reading or altering protected operating system data structures. Code
>   running in kernel mode has access to both user space and system space.
>   That is, code running in kernel mode has access to system space and
>   the virtual address space of the current user-mode process.
>
> ...

It's also worthwhile to note the difference betwee *kernel mode* and *user mode*:

> [User mode and kernel mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode)
>
> When you start a user-mode application, Windows creates a process for
>   the application. The process provides the application with a private
>   virtual address space and a private handle table. Because an
>   application's virtual address space is private, one application cannot
>   alter data that belongs to another application. Each application runs
>   in isolation, and if an application crashes, the crash is limited to
>   that one application. Other applications and the operating system are
>   not affected by the crash.
>
> ...
>   In addition to being private, the virtual address space of a user-mode application is limited. A processor running in user mode
>   cannot access virtual addresses that are reserved for the operating
>   system. Limiting the virtual address space of a user-mode application
>   prevents the application from altering, and possibly damaging,
>   critical operating system data.
>
> ...

Comment: [Memory and Address Space Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#memory_limits) - *Limit in 64-bit Windows - 4 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set*

Comment: Windows Server 2008 was the first OS Microsoft released for 64-bit only. "/LARGEADDRESSAWARE" is an [anachronism](https://www.yourdictionary.com/anachronism) - it's not used/not needed in current versions of Windows.

Comment: `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` this is linker option. it set `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics` and of course it is not anachronism

Comment: 32- (and DOS 16-) bit apps *ARE* anachronisms.  The OPs original question appeared to be about runtime, not compiling/linking.  As far as source-level issues: A) the application shouldn't know - or care - if a pointer value is less than or greater than 2^31, B) To the extent an application might need >> 2GB contiguous space, it would be wise to build the application for 64-bits anyway.  The *MAIN* points I was *TRYING* to convey:  A) "user space" vs.  "system space", B) the distinction between physical and virtual addresses in either space, and C)  "user mode" vs. "kernel mode".

Comment: until 32bit apps not anachronisms by fact. how application is linked affect runtime. i simply note that if we set `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag in 32bit PE - 64bit windows let to him operate with 4GB space. without this flag - only 2GB. tehcnically this is done by *reserve* (so prevent from allocate) some memory space from `FFFE0000` (if 4gb) or `7FFF0000` up to 64 bit ntdll.dll usually.